# Variable access from within inner class

Tags: java, android

I created a function for checking fence state in Awareness API. But I need to return the result. So I declared Boolean but it requires me to declare it to be final. Can you help me with solution how to return this value?

```
public static boolean isFencesActive(final Context context) {

    boolean isActive;

    Awareness.getFenceClient(context).queryFences(FenceQueryRequest.forFences(Arrays.asList(Constans.DETECTION_FENCE_DRIVING, Constans.DETECTION_FENCE_WALKING)))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FenceQueryResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FenceQueryResponse fenceQueryResponse) {

                    FenceStateMap map = fenceQueryResponse.getFenceStateMap();
                    isActive = !map.getFenceKeys().isEmpty(); //Needs to be final
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed: " + e);
                    isActive = false;
                }
            });

    return isActive;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some consideration I understood that is asynchronous task and that is why I receive false. What I did is created callbacks that send this info to my activity.

Answer (score 0):

@Dim, You have to use like below code(Using that you are to achieve what you want):

```
public static void isFencesActive(final Context context) {
   Awareness.getFenceClient(context).queryFences(FenceQueryRequest.forFences(Arrays.asList(Constans.DETECTION_FENCE_DRIVING, Constans.DETECTION_FENCE_WALKING)))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FenceQueryResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FenceQueryResponse fenceQueryResponse) {

                    FenceStateMap map = fenceQueryResponse.getFenceStateMap();
                    if(!map.getFenceKeys().isEmpty()){
                      //Perform your operation here is the better way
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed: " + e);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Please do not just paste a block of code but explain what you did to solve the problem(s) the original poster faced.

Comment: This is a workaround, not the actual solution. And also I believe OnSuccessListener execute asynchronously and there is a very possibility that isActive[0] return before it set and you will get unexpected result

Answer (score -1):

This may help you , Please declare `boolean isActive;` variable globally.